# Neo4j check relationship Python

Tags: python, neo4j

I have graph in Neo4j, and I want to set the relationship between 2 nodes.
For two nodes, 2 arrows are created in different directions, can I somehow replace it with one bidirectional one?
[image]

```
for node in nodes_of_mobile:
        if nodes_mobile[node]['social_contact'] != 0:
            for neighbor in nodes_mobile[node]["social_contact"]:
                command = "MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person) WHERE " \
                          f"a.id='{node}' AND " \
                          f"b.id='{neighbor}' " \
                          "CREATE (a)-[r:Network]->(b)"
                graph_Neo4j.run(command)
```

I use python to fill in the links. If you can't create bidirectional relationships, can you determine if there is a specific type of connection between nodes and not repeat them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't have a concept of a bi-directional (or directionless) relationship.

To handle creating a relationship only if it doesn't already exist, use the Neo4j [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge) command instead of CREATE.